# Приложение отклонено. Изображения с авторским правом

Tags: google-play, авторские-права

Привет, в моём приложении собраны 100 фото знаменитостей. Когда я делал приложение, я не думал что его могут отклонить по причине нарушения авторских прав фото. Что делать? Придётся менять все фото или вовсе убирать?

Comment: ruSO создано для вопросов технического характера

Comment: Наймите юриста, который за фантастические деньги выиграет спор с гуглем ;)

Comment: Взять фотоаппарат и переснять всех

Comment: я считаю, вопросы связанные с модерацией в магазин приложений подходят для сайта

Comment: Нормальный вопрос - че взъелись то?

Comment: @Visman Отличная идея!) Следует сделать именно так. Вопрос можно считать решённым :). (нет)

Comment: @Barmaley Спасибо. Видимо, из-за того, что данная проблема встречается довольно редко, поэтому и поставили минусы. Хотя, может, это из-за того, что я умудрился собрать 100 фото знаменитостей и при этом не предведил результата.

Comment: Данный вопрос следует закрыть, потому что этот вопрос нужно задавать юристу.

Comment: @Suvitruf, тогда всю метку [tag:авторские-права] надо позакрывать как нетематическую.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Как вариант, взять фото из нормального фотохостинга, типа [Flickr](https://www.flickr.com). Проблема с копирайтом возникает не из-за фото знаменитостей, а из-за того, что вы накачали непонятных фото из сети, что может нарушать чьи то авторские права на именно эти фото.

Фото из того же Flickr можно использовать только если:

> You can only use photographs from Flickr which carry a Creative Commons License.

то есть если выложенное фото лицензировано [Creative Commons License](http://creativecommons.ru/licenses)

Подробнее по таким фотографиям на Flickr [здесь](https://www.flickr.com/creativecommons/)

Идеальный вариант воспользоваться [API Flickr](https://www.flickr.com/services/developer/api/) и показывать фото прямо из фотохостинга (с кэшем на локальном устройстве)

Кроме Flickr естественно есть масса других фотохостингов - тот же Яндекс фото, но Flickr самая продвинутая.

Comment: Не пойму, какую лицензию выбирать. Здесь и attribution license и attribution-nodevirs license и др. И придётся же потом указывать имя правообладателя? Если да, то можно на каждом фото написать? Или стоит создать отдельное какое-то активити, где будет список правообладетелей фото. И спасибо за ответ!)

Comment: @Zeltam работайте. Все что необходимо написано. Лицензию которые вы выбираете зависит от вашего приложения  - коммерческое, некоммерческое и проч. Читайте описания лицензий и решайте.

Comment: Ладно, просто всё на английском, думал, Вы уже знаете. Моё приложение абсолютно бесплатное, без рекламы и платного контента. Эх, придётся разбираться) Ещё раз спасибо за ответ. Stack Overflow и его участники меня выручают уже не в первый раз) Спасибо, что Вы есть! :)

Answer (score 1):

Как вариант - держать эти фото на сервере, а приложение пусть тянет их, но в себе не содержит. Если надо оффлайн доступ - можно при первой загрузке приложения вытягивать все изображения и сохранять на устройстве. Тогда вроде не должны по этой причине отклонить - фактически само приложение в себе не содержит авторского контента. Это один из вариантов решения вопроса, если посоветуетесь с юристами - может подскажут более оригинальное решение

Comment: Извините, что только сейчас отвечаю.
Вы не знаете как сделать так, чтобы после загрузки приложение скачивало с сервера изображения и сохраняло их в определённую папку проекта? 
И ещё мне отклонили приложение, как я понял, только по скриншотам. Они увидели, что в скриншотах есть фото знаменитостей. Хочу спросить, как сделать скриншоты в этом случае? На скриншотах же не будет видно, что приложение в себе не содержит авторского контента. В этом случае, наверное, стоит вместо скриншотов показать какие-то фотки, на которых что-то написано. Хотя эти картинки не привлекут пользователей(

Comment: Хотя, если сохранять в определённую папку приложения (app\src\main), получается, что приложение содержит авторский контент. Вы имели в виду сохранять изображения отдельно от приложения во внутренней памяти?